# Estimote Beacons - How to match EstimoteTelemetry with Beacon

Tags: ibeacon, beacon, estimote, telemetry

I am using Estimote beacons to determine if something moved.  This is done by monitoring which beacons are in range (MonitoringListener) and which beacons have moved (TelemetryListener).

The problem is EstimoteTelemetry has a field UniqueId but Beacon uses UUID, Major and Minor to determine the unique beacon.  EstimoteTelemetry does not broadcasat UUID, Major and Minor..

I need to know which beacon is broadcasting the telemetry packets.  I can't see any fields that are the same in both.  Anyone know how to do this on Android or iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned there are no data fields in the BT packets that are shared among iBeacon and Telemetry packets. These are completely independent packets and contain different set of information. It is not possible to use iBeacon identification in telemetry packet - it takes too much space so telemetry data would be extremely limited.

If you need to collect both packets and keep them together look-up table in your app/server is the only solution. Estimote does not provide this kind of functionality.

Each Estimote beacon has single non-changing identifier (16 bytes) assigned during production. Telemetry packet contains first half of it (8 bytes). You need to create table where this 8 bytes are related to exact iBeacon identification you use.

Comment: Thanks Marcin.  I realise that the id in EstimoteTelemetry packet is in the Estimote admin panel settings for that beacon.  I have added this id my back-end DB along with uuid, major and minor.  This works well, thanks!